# Consume WCF service in Xamarin Cross Platform Application (Shared Project)

Tags: web-services, wcf, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

i try to consume a WCF service(SOAP) to my cross-platform app via **shared project**

1. I add the WCF as service reference to the UWP project and call it to the namespace
   `using MyApp.UWP.CalculateWCF;`
   it works when running ONLY UWP
2. I add the WCF as Web reference to the Android project and call it to the namespace
   `using MyApp.Droid.CalculateWCF;`
   it works when running ONLY Android

When trying to make preprocessor conditional statement like

```
#if __ANDROID__
using MyApp.Droid.CalculateWCF;
#else
using MyApp.UWP.CalculateWCF;
#endif
```

Output brings 1 error for Android  and 1 for UWP

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICalculateWCFClient' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) (250, 25)
>
> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CalculateWCF' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   (290, 25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i found is to leave the shared project and convert it to .NET standard,

Then add the service in the base project though 
*Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider*